# How to save distance results for Distance Matrix API in PHP to calculate fare with formula

Tags: javascript, php, google-distancematrix-api

I created a form using PHP to add booking and to calculate fare before adding the booking. I am using Google Places API for Auto-fill Addresses. When User Click on Calculate Fare Button it shows the Distance in Miles, Kilometers, Total Time, In Minutes below the form using JS and displays in  using ID.

The question is How to save those values in PHP variables because I have to perform fare calculation to display and save those values in DB.

Since I am not good in JS and I Haven't find anything close to my issue. That is why I am writing it here.

*Calculating Result Code*

```
function calculateDistance() {
    var origin = $('#origin').val();
    var destination = $('#destination').val();
    var service = new google.maps.DistanceMatrixService();
    service.getDistanceMatrix(
        {
            origins: [origin],
            destinations: [destination],
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
            unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.IMPERIAL, // miles and feet.
            // unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.metric, // kilometers and meters.
            avoidHighways: false,
            avoidTolls: false
        }, callback);
}
```

*Getting Calculated Results*

```
function callback(response, status) {
            if (status != google.maps.DistanceMatrixStatus.OK) {
                $('#result').html(err);
            } else {
                var origin = response.originAddresses[0];
                var destination = response.destinationAddresses[0];
                if (response.rows[0].elements[0].status === "ZERO_RESULTS") {
                    $('#result').html("Better get on a plane. There are no roads between "  + origin + " and " + destination);
                } 

                else {
                    var distance = response.rows[0].elements[0].distance;
                    var duration = response.rows[0].elements[0].duration;
                    console.log(response.rows[0].elements[0].distance);
                    var distance_in_kilo = distance.value / 1000; // the kilom
                    var distance_in_mile = distance.value / 1609.34; // the mile
                    var duration_text = duration.text;
                    var duration_value = duration.value;
                    $('#in_mile').text(distance_in_mile.toFixed(2));
                    $('#in_kilo').text(distance_in_kilo.toFixed(2));
                    $('#duration_text').text(duration_text);
                    $('#duration_value').text(duration_value);
                }
            }
        }
```

*Displaying Results in*

```
<div id="result">
<ul class="list-group">

<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Distance in Miles<span  id="in_mile" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
</li>

<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Distance in Kilometers<span  id="in_kilo" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
</li>

<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">Total Time<span  id="duration_text" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
</li>

<li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">In Seconds<span  id="duration_value" class="badge badge-primary badge-pill"></span>
</li>
```

*Images*
[Screenshot for better understanding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roPOp.png)

Comment: use `<input type="hidden"/>` and send along with other form fields

Comment: Add `<input type="hidden" name="in_miles">` to your form and fill in the value after calculation.

Comment: replace <span> with textboxes within form with same IDs as <span>?

Comment: I got it but those values will pass if the user submits the form but I wan to calculate values on the same pages below distance values are displaying before submitting the form to BOOK NOW.

Comment: Have you considered doing the calculation server side? If you do it client side, the user could edit the fare price.

Comment: @atymic Can you please explain it to me? TIA